# How to measure elapsed time, including across device reboots and without regard for possibly-manually-changed system time?

Tags: ios, clock

What is the best way to measure the elapsed time between any two points, including across device reboot? I thought `clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` would work but I recently realized that the clock restarts when the device reboots.

In my understanding different solutions based on system clock time would change if the user changes the device time, which is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonable guarantee of network connectivity for your application, you could leverage NTP with an NTP client like [`instacart/TrueTime.swift`](https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift) to get the current time from an NTP server you control or trust at the start and end of the time span you wish to measure.

Keep in mind that NTP (at its core) is rather vulnerable to MiTM attacks by motivated attackers (or outright firewall blocking of its UDP port 123 by heavy-handed system administrators), so the acceptability of this as a solution will depend heavily on your threat model.